# BinarySearch using Recursion in Java

Tags: java

I am learning recursion so trying to practise it by implementing BinarySearch algorithm.

```
public class BinarySearch {
    public int search(int[] items, int searchTerm, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        int midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex)/2 ;
        System.out.println("Midpoint: "+midIndex);
        if(searchTerm == items[midIndex]) {
            return midIndex;
        } else if(searchTerm > items[midIndex]) {
            search(items, searchTerm, midIndex, endIndex);
        } else if(searchTerm < items[midIndex]) {
            search(items, searchTerm, startIndex, midIndex);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearch bs = new BinarySearch();
        int[] items = { 1, 7, 9, 11, 22, 55, 67 };
        int index = bs.search(items, 7, 0, items.length-1);
        System.out.println(index);
    }

}
```

`search` is the method that is called recursively with array of items, the value that I want to search and start & end index of the array where item could potentially be there.

First, I get the midpoint and if the item at midpoint matches the `searchTerm` then I return it. If `searchTerm` is greater than value at midpoint then I call the search method again with  midpoint as `startIndex` and last item in the array as `endIndex`.

Similarly, if searchTerm is less than value at midpoint, then pass startIndex and midpoint as start and end value to search in.

Lets say, I want to search for 7. In the first iteration, 3 would be the midpoint so value at index 3 would be 11. Since, 7 < 11, search will be called again with startIndex as 0 and endIndex as 3. Now, midpoint would be 7, so the index of 7 (which is 1) should be returned. However, the value returned is -1 which is not correct.

When I tried troubleshooting it using Eclipse debugger, I found that even after the match is found at

```
if(searchTerm == items[midIndex]) {
            return midIndex;
}
```

instead of exiting the method, the below code gets executed

```
else if(searchTerm < items[midIndex]) {
            search(items, searchTerm, startIndex, midIndex);
        }
```

And then it returns -1. I feel it could be something to do with recursion as the previous invocation of `search()` would still be in the stack due to recursive nature of the code and it might be popping out of the stack. However, I can't really understand it. What would be the correct way to implement `BinarySearch` using recursion?

Comment: You're not returning the result of your recursive call: `return search(items, searchTerm, startIndex, midIndex);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning your recursive calls.

```
    public int search(int[] items, int searchTerm, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        int midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex)/2 ;
        System.out.println("Midpoint: "+midIndex);
        if(searchTerm == items[midIndex]) {
            return midIndex;
        } else if(searchTerm > items[midIndex]) {
            return search(items, searchTerm, midIndex, endIndex);
        } else if(searchTerm < items[midIndex]) {
            return search(items, searchTerm, startIndex, midIndex);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Recursion works with a Method Stack as you may know. So when you don't return the value back when you find the element, Your final recursion call will always return -1 as it is the last line in the method.

That is why you got -1.

Comment: Thank you, that did fix it. Can you please shed some light on what does returning recursive calls imply? Shouldn't the method be added to execution stack regardless?

Comment: @swati the method is called, but its results are discarded. Then, the `return -1` at the end is called. You can see this more clearly in Eclipse if you comment out the final `return -1;` statement: you should get an error.

Comment: This code doesn’t compile, as now that the missing `return` statements have been included, the last `return -1;` is unreachable code. Actually, even the `else { return -1; }` clause is dead code, as when comparing two `int` values the result must be one of “equal”, “greater”, or “smaller”, but that won’t be checked by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int search(int[] items, int searchTerm, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
  int midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2; 
  if (startIndex > endIndex)
    return -1;
  else if (searchTerm == items[midIndex]) 
    return midIndex;
  else if (searchTerm < items[midIndex]) 
    return search(items, searchTerm, startIndex, midIndex - 1);
  else // (searchTerm > items[midIndex]) 
    return search(items, searchTerm, midIndex + 1, endIndex);
}
```

In this version of the binary search I used `midIndex ± 1`: I did this because in your if statement you already check if `items[midIndex]` is equal or not to `searchTerm`, that's why considering `items[midIndex]` in the next calls is unnecessary.

Comment: `midIndex ± 1` is even *necessary*, as otherwise, this code could end up in an infinite recursion when the value is not in the array. +1